# How to set a Jetpack Compose Slider to full width?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

For some reason there is some default padding....

```
Slider(
            value = currentDurationInMillis.toFloat(),
            onValueChange = onSliderValueChange,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .height(24.dp)
            ,
            valueRange = 0f..totalDurationInMillis.toFloat(),
            colors = SliderDefaults.colors(
                thumbColor = color_violet_4,
                activeTrackColor = color_violet_4,
                inactiveTrackColor = Color.White
            ),
        )
```

[Here you can see that padding when you compare it to the time labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xamyt.png)

I tried to add this to Slider() but it is not working....

```
track = { sliderPositions ->
                SliderDefaults.Track(
                    sliderPositions = sliderPositions,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
                    )
            }
```

Comment: The "padding" you refer to is half the thumb width, you need that space so that when the slider is at the leftmost or rightmost edge the thumb can dispay fully.

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: Pad the other composables.